Error no se permite la carga de recursos locales
El navegador no carga los links hacia otra secciones que hice de la pagina web. Me marca un error en la consola, no cambia cuando le hago click. Ese es el error que me marca:

Not allowed to load local resource.
file:///C:/Users/Usuario....


Me funciona en el ordenador, pero no cuando subo la página al servidor. ¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Tus links apuntan a archivos locales, eso no se puede hacer por medidas de seguridad del navegador web. Para que funcionen, tienes que usar rutas relativas. Por ejemplo, en vez de <a href="file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/GitHub/musica/Proyectovoluntariado/ps1.html">Juegos de Playstation 1</a> poner <a href="ps1.html">Juegos de Playstation 1</a>, en vez de <a href="file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/GitHub/musica/Proyectovoluntariado/pc.html">Juegos de PC</a>, poner <a href="pc.html">Juegos de PC</a>, etc.

gracias, funciono

@Mady pon eso como respuesta

@Nahuel dale un +1 y acepta la respuesta de Mady cuando la escriba :)

@AlvaroMontoro lo puse como comentario porque no quería escribir una respuesta xd, igual gracias por la sugerencia :P

@Mady Pensaba que la respuesta era tuya! Si la pones, te daré un +1 también :)

El mensaje indica el problema, estás tratando de cargar un recurso que se encuentra en tu computadora,

Not allowed to load local resource. file:///C:/Users/Usuario....

Esto no es posible por cuestiones de seguridad, si deseas cargar recursos en tu página debes usar rutas relativas o absolutas, por ejemplo:

URL absoluta: Una dirección URL absoluta contiene toda la información
necesaria para localizar un recurso.

<a href="https://www.misitio.com/archivo.html">Enlace absoluto</a>


URL Relativa: Una dirección URL relativa localiza un recurso mediante una dirección
URL absoluta como punto de partida. En efecto, la "dirección URL
completa" del destino se especifica concatenando las direcciones URL
absoluta y relativa. Una dirección URL relativa normalmente se compone
sólo de la ruta de acceso y, de manera opcional, del recurso, pero no
del esquema ni del servidor.

<a href="/archivo.html">Enlace relativo</a>

Te sugiero revisar la siguiente información:
Direcciones URL relativas y absolutas

Pensaba que esto era la respuesta de Mady :(

@AlvaroMontoro técnicamente lo es. Ella o el (no se que sea Mady) respondió o comentó dos horas antes que esta respuesta. Y que no se entienda que la excelente respuesta de Jorgesys no es válida, solo me apego a los tiempos de respuesta

@AlvaroMontoro no entendía a que te referirías, ya vi los comentarios :o, a veces solo respondo sin ver los comentarios, perdón :.(

No pasa nada. Igual te di +1. La respuesta es correcta.
